# Cracking a web form based logon with hydra

Tags: penetration-test, brute-force

### How do I have to use `hydra` on a web form?

---

**What I have done so far:**
I already successfully used hydra on a folder with an [HTTP authentication](https://library.linode.com/web-servers/apache/configuration/http-authentication):

```
http://localhost/test/authtest/
```

with user `admin` and password `1234`, I successfully found out the password with:

```
hydra -l admin -x 1:5:1 -t 1 -f -vV 127.0.0.1 http-get /test/authtest/
```

---

But how would I have to try a run **on a web form** like

```
http://127.0.0.1/test/login.php?&username=admin&password=1234
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically, you need to specify two things:

1. Where the username and password go.
2. How to determine success/failure of the request.

The first is accomplished with tokens like `^USER^` and `^PASS^` in the URL where they are to be replaced by the usernames and passwords under test.  The second is done by hydra by string matching against the returned page.  You can either test for a failure condition, such as "Bad password", or a success condition, such as "logged in".

Here's an example:

```
hydra 127.0.0.1 http-form-get '/test/login.php?username=^USER^&password=^PASS^:Bad password'
```

You can also test for a cookie being set with `C=cookie_name` or an HTTP header with `H=header_name` in place of "Bad password" for the test condition for a successful login.

In case the login form uses POST, rather than GET, (as many do) you should use the http-form-post "protocol".  You'll also need to use `:` to separate the URL and the POST parameters, rather than the `?` in a query string.  There's also https variations, which are (unsurprisingly) prefixed with `https-`, rather than `http-`.

Comment: I get an error when I try this: `hydra -l admin -x 1:8:1 -t 1 -f -vV 127.0.0.1 http-form-post '/login.php?username=^USER^&password=^PASS^:Bad password'` The Error is: `[ERROR] the variables argument needs at least the strings ^USER^ or ^PASS^: Bad password`

Comment: Modified to clarify the answer, but TL;DR is separate post variables with a :.  For example `'login.php:username=^USER^&password=^PASS^:Bad password'`.

Comment: Thanks that worked, maybe you add my example for a post form and auto generation of passwords from 0 up to 99999999 to your post

Comment: I am getting false positives. I guess due to the fast rate of requests sometimes my server doesn't deliver the whole page and the part with "Bad password" is missing, so hydra thinks the password worked. Shouldn't hydra verify the password before stopping?

Comment: Consider using "S=Good Password" instead, so it will look for an affirmative response.  Though then you might get false negatives if an error occurs on a valid password.

Comment: In a test-scenario, you would know a "Good Password" response, but in a real surrounding, you usually don't

Comment: Depends: if it's off the shelf software, or you are able to find out details about the software, you might know the right response.  Otherwise, use the bad password or cookie criteria.  (If you know what the session cookie looks like and it is not set until login succeeds.)  Maybe reduce rate to avoid false positives?

Comment: It should be easy to apply a [hydra verification before stopping](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/136574)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15037/discussion-between-rubo77-and-david).